# Problem About GPL Licence And WordPress Products

Tags: premium

I copied following answer from [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/59457/ways-to-create-a-paid-wordpress-plugin/59458#59458).

> Since WordPress is GPL code, all code publicly distributed must also
>   be licensed either as GPL, or GPL compatible.
>
> The GPL states you cannot charge for code, but you can charge for
>   distribution. So when you buy gravity forms, you're not paying for the
>   plugin, you're playing for the downloading and acquisition of the
>   plugin.
>
> **Once you have the plugin it is perfectly legal to burn it to a CD and
>   mail it to 20,000 people free of charge. You won't get the support or
>   updates ( unless you pay them again, or you have a support contract ),
>   and it'd be a pretty nasty thing to do ( they have a business! ), but
>   it's perfectly legal**.

If above is true, why many plugin authors sell plugin via "1 site Licence", "2 Site Licence", "Unlimited site Licence".

According to above answer **even though I buy "1 site Licence", I should able to use it on unlimited sites as well as my clients sites legally**? Is it correct?

Comment: Simply: not everybody follows the GPL obligations correctly, not everybody do things correctly and not everybody understand GPL correctly. Also, [not everybody understand GPL license in the same way](https://ma.tt/2016/10/wix-and-the-gpl/). I tink it is better if you ask this question to a lawyer or in [Legal StackExchange](http://law.stackexchange.com/), issues with GPL license is not something specific to WordPress and it is not a practical software development question, not sure if your question fits in [the scope of this site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is hard to answer in general, without looking at *specific* case of what sale of license implies for specific product.

For general GPL compliance note that what is typically licensed *is not code*. You just get code provided. What *license* buys you are usually things like access to **support and updates**. GPL doesn't regulate those.

So yes, you can buy license for 1 site and install it on a hundred of sites. But then vendor will detect it and will drop their obligation to support it and give you access to updates.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Then what about giving it free for premium members. For a example I have a premium membership site. Can I give access to download those plugins and themes for my premium members. " Can I promote my site like this. If you become a premium member of my site you can free download these theses premium plugins and themes. But you won't give any updates or supports". Can I do something like that?

Comment: Yes, there are in practice sites like this. Note they are considered to be in very poor taste by many in community and by spreading extensions without possibility of proper update you make users vulnerable to security issues in the long run.