# Implications of creating a plugin that adds functionality to other developer's plugin?

Tags: plugin-development

I'm thinking in writing a plugin that alow users to import quizes on an existing LMS plugin, that functionality isn't even exists on the paid version of the existing plugin.

Is there any legal impediments of publishing that plugin on the wordpress.org repositories?.

As [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/59457/ways-to-create-a-paid-wordpress-plugin#) states, any plugin published on wordpress.org is under GPL license (the LMS plugin falls in this category), but the paid version is not under those terms.

I don't plan to charge for the plugin, maybe open a donation channel, but mostly I just want to make it as a portfolio item to show to possible employers.

Answer (score 0):

If a version of the plugin is available under the GPL then you risk nothing by creating your work and releasing it under the same GPL.

If there's a reason you don't want to publish your code under the GPL, then it gets more complicated.

I referred to [this](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/1579/when-is-my-project-a-derivative-work-in-an-interpreted-language) which gives clarity about what is a 'derived' work, and I believe if you use the datastructure or code from another plugin and rely on it for your code to work (e.g. you call a function from that code) then it's reasonable that your project is 'derived' and therefore subject to GPL.

But it's not really worth arguing the point if you're happy to publish it under the GPL anyway - then you're covered either way.

Comment: Thank you for your response, indeed I like the idea of release my work under GPL, I just hope that doesn't bother the agency that created the original plugin.

Comment: @J.R.Ramirez The GPL is speciifc permission for you to do this! :-) It's also often nice to write to people and ask. Usually people are happy to see that their work is used and built on, and they may even like to know about your work